# is the linux directory inode different then the file inode?

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory, inode

Im currently reading the book

- "How Linux Works" by Brian Ward

and on chapter 4.5 it is said

> "A directory inode contains a list of filenames and corresponding
> links to other inodes"

this implies that a directory's inode is structurally different than a normal file inode.

[I have found this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325294/how-does-a-directory-inode-keep-its-file-list)

and the top ( and only ) answer there implies this is isn't correct.( it agrees with Brian Ward but the answer is highly downvoted)

if the answer I'm looking for is filesystem specific take ext2/3/4 as example

Comment: The site where you found the other question is far better suited for this question, so I'm voting to migrate it over to [unix.se].

Comment: That is a simplistic/conceptual view.  For actual implementation details, have a look at the `ext4` documentation at `kernal.org` at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/directory.html